# Unity PropertyDrawer override drag-and-drop implementation on list/array types

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I have a custom `PropertyDrawer` in Unity, and I want to override the existing drag-and-drop functionality to do some extra validation on the dragged object/s.

I found [this script](https://gist.github.com/bzgeb/3800350#file-triggercontainereditor-cs-L24) which works great after some modifications:

```
public void DropAreaGUI(Rect dropArea, SerializedProperty property)
{
    Event evt = Event.current;
    switch (evt.type)
    {
        case EventType.DragUpdated:
        case EventType.DragPerform:
            if (!dropArea.Contains(evt.mousePosition) || DragAndDrop.objectReferences.Length > 1)
                return;

            Object draggedObject = DragAndDrop.objectReferences[0];
            if (!IsValidObject(draggedObject))
            {
                DragAndDrop.visualMode = DragAndDropVisualMode.Rejected;
                return;
            }

            DragAndDrop.visualMode = DragAndDropVisualMode.Link;
            if (evt.type == EventType.DragPerform)
            {
                DragAndDrop.AcceptDrag();
                serializedProperty.objectReferenceValue = draggedObject;
                serializedProperty.serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
                serializedProperty.serializedObject.Update();
            }
            evt.Use();
            break;
    }
}

public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
{
    DropAreaGUI(position, property);
    EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);
    EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property, label);
    EditorGUI.EndProperty();
}
```

The problem is with list/array types. Because the `PropertyDrawer` only applies to the individual elements, the user can drag any object (of the correct type) to the list/array header and it would be added to the list/array.

How can I override this behaviour and use the custom drag-and-drop I used above?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect solution, but: You could create a custom type that derives from List/Array for storing a collection of your custom objects, then create a Property Drawer for that collection class.

Users would still be able to get around that by defining their own lists, but as long as you use your custom list class in your code, it should render in the inspector how you like.

Comment: Interesting idea, unfortunately my custom objects are marked using an attribute so this solution won't work for me...